# Track login event with google analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

There's already a question similar to mine, but it doesn't tackle my problem.

I'm trying to set the google tag manager to track login events in my website.
But I can't identify the action related to the login event on the tag assistant.
Here is a print of the actions when I login:

[image]

None seem to be strictly related to the login event.
I tried to track some of these actions, but they occur in many other actions.
(thus, I collect data I don't need, as if they were login events)

What of these actions is related to the login event?
How can I precisely identify the login action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automatically implement data layer events on form submissions with ListenLayer.com.  In this case, you will likely need to use their Custom Forms Listener.

You have to create an account, place their script on your website, enable the Custom Forms listener and it's features and then identify your forms under the Listener's event settings. You would do this by writing a simple rule to match the CSS class, ID, or form Name element etc.  (these things would exist in the `<form>` tag.

Here you can see I have set some rules to identify a form like this

`<form class="form-container">` or `<form class="listenlayer">`

[image]

Publish and test on your website.

Now, when the form is submitted, the Listener will automatically push data into the data layer identifying the form and the action.

From there you would use GTM to register and read the data layer activity. I assume you know how to do that since you have the GTM debug view going, but basically you'll get a new message on the left side with an event name and you can create a Custom Event trigger in GTM and also register Data Layer Variables to use in your trigger. It's all down hill from there!

Answer (score 0):

With tracking you are usually left out with two approaches :

- Either you ask your developer to implement a dataLayer event on a specific action / interaction so that you can then use this as a "custom event" trigger in GTM. For instance, here, on the login success page, after the GTM snippet, the developer could invoke the following code:

dataLayer.push({ event: 'login' })

That will allow you to use 'login' as your event name in GTM custom event trigger.

- As you began doing, if your developer cannot implement it, you may try to identify variables that will help you isolate that specific action / page. For instance here, maybe does your successful login page has a specific URL you could use in a page view event, targeting that specific page path.

Comment: No. There's no page/action only "just-logged-in users" access/perform. That's why I was trying to create a tag, not to identify a variable. If I track clicks on the 'login' button, I'll have a similar data record, but with some error.

Comment: If no specific page path available and you are unable to implement the dataLayer event, maybe there are other information that could help you détermine the login action, like when user logs in, does je goes through a specific referer? You